# Propagate session name in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a role assumed by a user coming from Google workspace (`GoogleWorkspaceIdentityRole`). This role has no permissions. When I login to this role, the console identifies me as `GoogleWorkspaceIdentityRole/myemail@example.com` (shown in the account drop down at the top right).

I have a role called "Administrator" that I want (some) users to be able to assume.

That role has the AWS managed permission `AdminstratorAccess` attached, and the following trust policy:

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/GoogleWorkspaceIdentityRole"
    },
    "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:userId": [
                "<ROLE_ID>:myemail@example.com",
                "<ROLE_ID>:otheremail@example.com"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I assume that role (using the "switch role" link, or the button on the console), it successfully switches roles, and shows `Administrator` *without* the session name. For auditing, I want (at least) the session name part (`myemail@example.com`) to propagate when doing this role switch.

I've found [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-role-chaining) that suggests tags should propagate during role chaining.

This other [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#ck_rolesessionname) describes how I can enforce the session name is set, but only describes how to do it if the source identity is a `User` (where I have a `Role`).

Comment: What do you mean by "For auditing"? Are you wanting a particular name to appear in the AWS management console, or are you wanting it to appear in some type of log? More information, please.

Comment: The session name should show in CloudTrail (for auditing actions taken) and as an indicator in the management console.